# Escala logarítmica - Histograma R

Tags: r

Plotei um gráfico do tipo histograma, utilizando o seguinte código:

```
hist(dados1$Prec, breaks=40 , col=rgb(0.2,0.8,0.5,0.5) , border=F , main="" , xlab="Precipitação (mm)", xlim=c(0,140), ylim = c(0,10000))
```

Preciso colocar o histograma em escala logaritmica para que as outras classes (barras) possam aparecer também, devido a grande quantidade de valores que possuo. Como poderia fazer isso?

Segue a amostra dos meus dados:

```
dput(head(dados1$Prec,500))
c(8.9, 32.7, 0.3, 3.9, 8.8, 29.2, 2.5, 0.6, 27.7, 11.2, 9.8, 
0, 6.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.2, 0, 0, 19.4, 15.1, 
0.9, 16.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 10.1, 0.1, 0.2, 1.3, 2.4, 
2.6, 0, 0, 4.8, 0, 0.6, 7.1, 4.1, 0, 5, 0, 2.3, 6.3, 9.1, 25.7, 
8.3, 24, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19.8, 5.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 2.8, 6.9, 
51.6, 41.6, 58.9, 0.2, 0, 22.1, 0, 0, 2.3, 0, 2.2, 10.6, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 4, 0, 0.2, 0, 13.7, 0.7, 44.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20.2, 
0, 1.3, 0, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31.5, 
0, 6.8, 0, 0, 6.8, 11.6, 5.4, 1.8, 0, 0, 0.9, 0, 7.6, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.1, 3.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.1, 3.6, 14.2, 0, 6.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 
2.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.2, 12.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.2, 26.2, 
8, 0.5, 0, 0, 5.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.2, 0, 0, 30.9, 0, 4.1, 
1.6, 3.6, 10.7, 0, 0.5, 0, 31.5, 0, 6.6, 0.1, 2.8, 0, 0, 0, 2.4, 
0, 14.2, 0, 13.5, 0.2, 12.9, 3.8, 0, 0, 93.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1.4, 0.3, 38.6, 0, 14.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0, 6.2, 40.4, 1.1, 0, 1.2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5, 1.6, 5.6, 0, 12.6, 0.3, 7, 35.6, 0.6, 0, 
0, 5.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 16.3, 33.6, 46.8, 35, 0, 0, 0, 13.2, 0.9, 
0.2, 0, 46.2, 0, 0, 2.8, 3.6, 20.1, 9.3, 16.3, 11.1, 0, 0.1, 
0.6, 27.9, 14.9, 22.1, 5.7, 0, 2.4, 9.4, 0.5, 0, 24.4, 0, 6.3, 
7.2, 15.4, 0.8, 0, 50.1, 4, 18.6, 0.8, 0.2, 25.3, 16.6, 0.9, 
0, 0.1, 2.4, 0.4, 0, 0, 5.3, 0, 39.8, 0, 22.5, 5.8, 2.7, 0, 9.2, 
23.6, 0, 0, 0, 51.7, 0, 10.7, 33.5, 24.6, 4, 0, 3.1, 5.9, 38.4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25.7, 0, 7, 0, 7.6, 0, 0.2, 2.3, 0.2, 18.3, 32, 
10.2, 32.3, 2.2, 1, 14.3, 1.7, 0.8, 11.4, 0.3, 0, 0, 43, 0, 12.2, 
2.8, 0, 0, 34.3, 32.1, 2, 0, 0, 9.9, 0.3, 11.2, 2, 5.3, 4.3, 
1.2, 0, 0, 7.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Histograma é um gráfico de barras com a contagem de elementos por intervalo. Pode calcular as informações com a função `hist` e usar `barplot` para gerar o gráfico com ajustes:

```
histPrec <- hist(dados1$Prec, breaks = 40, plot = FALSE)
```

O gráfico de barras de `histPrec$counts` será o mesmo que o histograma de `dados1$Prec`:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
hist(dados1$Prec, breaks = 40)
barplot(histPrec$counts, space = 0)
axis(1, at = 0:length(histPrec$counts), labels = histPrec$breaks)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para colocar o eixo em escala log, basta usar a opção `log`. Mas como há intervalos que possuem contagem 0, irá retornar erro. Pode lidar com isso de algumas maneiras: 1) plotar log(counts) e não transformar o eixo; 2) usar counts+1; 3) substituir as contagens 0 por NA.

```
counts.sem.zero <- histPrec$counts
counts.sem.zero[counts.sem.zero == 0] <- NA

par(mfrow = c(1,3))
barplot(log(histPrec$counts), ylim = c(0, log(max(histPrec$counts))), ylab = "log(frequência)")
barplot(histPrec$counts+1, log = "y", ylim = c(1, max(histPrec$counts+1)), ylab = "frequência + 1")
barplot(counts.sem.zero, log = "y", ylab = "frequência")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recomendo o último, já que não há modificação nos valores, o que torna a interpretação do eixo Y mais direta.

Comment: Carlos Eduardo, eu preciso que os valores que estão zero "0" sejam contabilizados, nesse caso eles não podem ser considerados NA. Teria alguma sugestão quanto a isso?

Comment: Editei a resposta para incluir outras opções, mas recomendo trocar os zeros por NA. A troca é feita nos dados para plotar o histograma, não altera o data.frame original.

Comment: Carlos Eduardo, muito obrigada pelo auxílio até o momento! Editei minha pergunta para te mostrar como ficou meu histograma com a alteração feita e infelizmente não consegui perceber qual o problema ocorre em meu código. Uma dúvida ainda é se nesse caso, os valores "0" estão sendo contabilizados na primeira barra do histograma, pois não aparecem os intervalos entre as classes.

Comment: Você usou os dados brutos, não a contagem gerada pela `hist`. O eixo pode ser adicionado com `axis`, como no meu primeiro exemplo. Não coloquei no segundo para deixar o exemplo mais limpo.

Answer (score 1):

Pode-se definir uma função que chama primeiro `hist` com `plot = FALSE` de modo a obter o vetor de contagens. Se `counts == 0` atribui-se-lhes o valor `NA` para não aparecerem no gráfico. Assim o R não calcula os logaritmos de 0. Finalmente, usa-se `barplot` para traçar o gráfico.

```
hist_logy <- function(x, breaks = "Sturges", plot = TRUE, ...){
  h <- hist(x, breaks = breaks, plot = FALSE)
  is.na(h$counts) <- h$count == 0
  if(plot) barplot(setNames(h$counts, h$mids), log = "y", space = 0, ...)
  invisible(h)
}

hist_logy(x)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
hist_logy(x, breaks = "FD", col = "cyan")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]